# Re Legend values repeating in SSRS chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, legend, ssrs-2008-r2, label

I have a small prob in my chart legend. It shows like below at present. I just want to see AP1, AP2, PRIN and just one Total. Is this possible?

[image: legend]

Comment: Please provide more information about what you want, what you did to do it, and what errors you have triying to do the taks. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a series from appearing in the legend by going to the series properties and ticking **'Do not show this series in a legend'**. How your chart is set up at the moment, you could do this to all but one of your Total series so that only one shows in the legend.

However, it may be more beneficial to make it clear what each separate total is calculating. If each is totalling a different set of data, you should make their styles different and change the Custom Legend Text to specify what is being totalled. If all the totals are supposed to be the same (i.e. Total = AP1 + AP2 + PRIN) you should check your calculations and only include the series on the chart once.